# Error while iterating list to put those into a key value pairs in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I am new to python . I have a python list **old_ecim_mims_list** like below :-

```
['ReqSyncPort_v2_5_0', 'ECIM_SwM_v2_1_0_2_2', 'ECIM_SwM_v3_0_0_2_3', 'ResPowerDistribution_v1_0_0', 'ECIM_SwM_v4_2_0_3_2', 'ResPowerDistribution_v3_4_1', 'LratBb_v1_8025_0']
```

Now my requirement is here to iterate it and put it into a map like below key value pairs structure :-

```
ReqSyncPort=ReqSyncPort_v2_5_0
ECIM_SwM=ECIM_SwM_v2_1_0_2_2,ECIM_SwM_v3_0_0_2_3,ECIM_SwM_v4_2_0_3_2
ResPowerDistribution=ResPowerDistribution_v1_0_0,ResPowerDistribution_v3_4_1
LratBb=LratBb_v1_8025_0
```

I have done a sample program for this but I am getting error while executing :-

```
old_ecim_mims_map={} ;
for index , item in enumerate(old_ecim_mims_list) :
    print(index , item ) ;
    split_str=item.split("_v");
    #print(split_str[0]);
    if split_str[0] in old_ecim_mims_map :
        new_prop_map[split_str[0]].append(item);
        #old_ecim_mims_map.update({split_str[0]:item }) ;
    else :
        old_ecim_mims_map[split_str[0]]=item ;
```

Error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/DeltaProject/com/dash/abinash/DeltaOperation/Createdelta.py", line 50, in <module>
    new_prop_map[split_str[0]].append(item);
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Suggest me where I am doing wrong .Searched lots of concepts , but those did not help me that much .Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Just before the offending line, print `new_prop_map[split_str[0]]`.  What is it? Should it have an 'append' method? Is it what you expected it to be??

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because you add a string as value in dictionary (map), instead of enclosing it in `[]` to make an array in last line (`old_ecim_mims_map[split_str[0]]=item`). Next time you come across same key, you try to append to string, not to array.

What you have to do (and managed to do) is first check whether a certain key is already in a map. If it is, then you can append to the list `old_ecim_mims_dict[key]`. If there is no such key, a `KeyError` will be raised and then you have to create **new list** and put `el` inside it.

```
old_ecim_mims_list = ['ReqSyncPort_v2_5_0', 'ECIM_SwM_v2_1_0_2_2', 'ECIM_SwM_v3_0_0_2_3', 'ResPowerDistribution_v1_0_0', 'ECIM_SwM_v4_2_0_3_2', 'ResPowerDistribution_v3_4_1', 'LratBb_v1_8025_0']
old_ecim_mims_map = {}

for el in old_ecim_mims_list:
    key, _ = el.split('_v')
    try:
        old_ecim_mims_map[key].append(el)
    except KeyError:
        old_ecim_mims_map[key] = [el]
```

This code is much cleaner. If you want to rewrite your code, just change last line to

```
old_ecim_mims_map[split_str[0]]=[item]
```

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, although I do *not* prefer this, it can be done by checking whether `key` is in map:

```
old_ecim_mims_list = ['ReqSyncPort_v2_5_0', 'ECIM_SwM_v2_1_0_2_2', 'ECIM_SwM_v3_0_0_2_3', 'ResPowerDistribution_v1_0_0', 'ECIM_SwM_v4_2_0_3_2', 'ResPowerDistribution_v3_4_1', 'LratBb_v1_8025_0']
old_ecim_mims_map = {}

for el in old_ecim_mims_list:
    key, _ = el.split('_v')
    if key in old_ecim_mims_map: # The same as if key in old_ecim_mims_map.keys()
        old_ecim_mims_map[key].append(el)
    else:
        old_ecim_mims_map[key] = [el]
```

Comment: Why not use `if key in dict.keys():`?

Comment: It works as well but... That approach will search whether `key` exists (is in `dict.keys()`. But then it will have to go through keys again to find the `key` to be able to append to it. With `try except` it will search for the `key` once, when trying to append to it. I agree it is easier to read `if key in dict.keys()` but once you get used to reading `try` clauses by skipping immediately to `except SomeError` to see what errors are possible,  and get familiar with Python, then you know exactly what and where that error can occur. Also, `try` is 3 letters, `if blahblahblah` is long ;)

Comment: @campovski , I tried your suggestion , It is working fine now .But I have a doubt in the below statement .can you clarify . key, _ = el.split('_v')

Comment: Underscore `_` means that you are not interested in that thing. If you would do `key, value = el.split('_v')`, you would save both sides of splitted `el` into memory, left side in `key` and right side in `value`. By doing `key, _ = el.split('_v')`, the left side gets stored in `key`, the right one nowhere. And since we don't need the right side, we can throw it away.